# Where's that "index.php" coming from after rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I added the following code to my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:.+/)?(\d+)/?$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The "L"-flag should prevent any forthcoming rules to apply, so I don't get why the URL

> www.domain.com/a/b/c/d/123

is rewritten to

> www.domain.com/index.php?id=123

I'm sure some of you can enlighten me!

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is:

```
^(?:.+/)?(\d+)/?$
```

Which is matching `/a/b/c/d` in first non-capturing group and capturing `123` in captured group #1.

Target is `?id=$1` which is rewriting above URL to `?id=123`.

Now `index.php` is default directory index due to `DirectoryIndex` directive hence it is invoking `index.php?id=123`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How can I prevent index.php being the default directory and just call /?id= ?

Comment: It is already calling `/?id=123`. What else do you want to be in place of `index.php` then?

Comment: Ok, got you. Fact is, if I enter the URL /?id=123 it works, if I enter /index.php?id=123 it doesn't work. But so this means htaccess is already correct and my fault lies elsewhere...

Comment: What error are you getting when you directly enter `/index.php?id=123` in browser?

Comment: It's a Wordpress site and it's just returning http 404 because of course it's not a valid WP site, but it should render startpage instead and pass along the query-parameters (because my plugin on the startpage will render contents depending on ?id ...

Comment: oh damn WP... of course WP doesn't like internal rewrites as it has its own rewrite module. You will need to use WP rewrite API.

Comment: Great tip @anubhava thank you!
So I tried:
add_rewrite_rule('^(?:.+/)?(\d+)/?$', 'index.php?id=$matches[1]', 'top');

but that does not work as well...

Comment: Yes as I wrote above, WP doesn't work with internal rewrite rules. **You will need to use WP rewrite API.**

Comment: That's what I did with the above code (in my comment) which I added to my themes functions.php

Comment: Ok, I forgot to flush the permalink-cache... it's almost working now (parameter is still empty). Thank you very much!